# Apache Camel: Sending exchange message header information to the endpoint

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

I am sending a xml from a seda queue to a JMS queue. I have some metadeta in exchange's header which I want to pass to the JMS queue.

Do I have to explicitly get the metadata from exchange object's header, Then set it to the xml? Or Is there anyway if Camel can do it out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"set it to the XML"? Camel will place the headers as camel exchange headers that will be converted automatically to JMS properties. There should be no XML involved. If you need the headers to be placed in the XML body, you need to do this manually.